# Default music app for bluetooth audio

Tags: bluetooth-audio

**Situation**: Connected to BT audio device, listening to Spotify app.  Press pause on the BT device (car stereo), then press play.

**Expected behaviour**:  The music being played by Spotify pauses, then resumes

**Actual behaviour**: The music being played by Spotify pauses, then the Apollo music player launches and starts playing.  Most likely to be completely different music.

**Extra information**: Apollo is the OEM music player which I occasionally use and don't want to uninstall.  HTC One X runnning Android 4.2.2 CyanogenMod 10.1

Can I fix this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific app to react to bluetooth commands, you have to set it to high priority. I know PowerAmp has such a setting. Check the spotify settings for a high priority option.

Comment: I could not find any priority option in spotify settings.